# Are all instructions eventually converted to zero-operand instructions?

Tags: computer-architecture

Recently, my demonstrator said that all instructions are eventually converted to zero-operand instructions just before they get executed. yet another demonstrator said that this "doesn't make any sense", and I don't know who to believe; none of them really gave any logical arguments.

So, I want to know is any of them right at all? I tried searching for the answer but I didn't find anything.

Comment: Once operands have been read (from memory or the register file) they effectively become immediates. If one does not count such as operands, the operation might be considered to have "zero operands".

Answer (score 3):

I agree with everyone else who said that this makes no sense. In fact, the opposite is closer to the truth: on most medium to high end CPUs that you will use today (i.e. everything from a mobile phone up), instructions are typically converted into *three*-operand instructions.

For example, if the CPU presents a two-operand addition instruction to the programmer, the CPU can convert this into a three-operand instruction using [register renaming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Register_renaming). By giving different names to the source and destination register, the CPU effectively eliminates WAR hazards.

Having said that, the microarchitecture may have a slightly different idea of what an "operand" is than a programmer is used to. Even if a source operand is a register, it could be filled in with an immediate value straight away if the CPU already knows the value (i.e. it doesn't depend on any previous unexecuted instructions). The destination of an instruction may not be a "register" (either physical or architectural), but a reorder buffer (ROB) entry, which allows for speculative execution.

Answer (score 1):

This will depend on the computer architecture.  zero-operand computer architectures use the stack, so to add 2+2:

1. PUSH 2 (into the stack),
2. PUSH 2 (again),
3. ADD (call the instruction - note that no operators are passed by).
4. POP ( 4 out of the stack)

but most other computer architectures e.g. use registers, memory addresses and values as the parameters to an instruction (in addition to the stack). For example the same 2+2 in a CISC computer.

1. MOX AX,02 (AX=0)
2. ADD AX,02 (AX=4)

However, if you're thinking in terms of translating a high level programming language into executable code e.g. one routine calling a subroutine the list of parameters most likely be passed by via stack and the number of parameters be reduced to 0 as in the first example.

Comment: I see, but the claim was that *regardless* of the machine type they'll always end up as zero-operand.

Comment: @UpsideDownTree Your professor probably said this in a specific context or example.

Comment: Well I didn't find what she said very logical, and I asked her repeatedly about it to make sure I didn't get things wrong, and no, she insisted, claiming it was way faster to execute zero-operand instructions.

Comment: If that was what she said, and there was no misunderstanding, then it is nonsense. Or she is an absolute genius and should go straight to Intel, AMD, Apple, Samsung etc. and tell them how to make their CPUs run way faster.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't make sense to me at all.

Usually instructions are split into more primitive instructions more suitable for processing (sometimes instructions are *combined* into primitive instructions), those primitive instructions are put into a queue, together with information about their operands and results, then when all operands are available, the instruction with its operands are sent to an execution unit, and finally the result is sent to its destination.

I'd like to hear your first demonstrator explain how zero-operand instructions are supposed to work. I suspect there is some massive misunderstanding somewhere.

Comment: Her take on it was something along this correct-fact-yet-not-a-valid-argument "Zero-operand instructions will use the stack pointer as an accumulator". I believe I've done every possible thing to make sure there was no misunderstanding. She's a recent graduate and is not expected to be a guru in the field. Especially in this crappy education system that we do have here.

Answer (score 1):

Many (but not all!) programming language implementations compile your human-readable source to some intermediate code.

The standard Java Virtual Machine (JVM), the Common Language Runtime (CLR), and many other runtimes / virtual machines require every operation in that intermediate code be be a zero-operand operand instruction, operating only on the stack.
(In other words, each one is a "stack machine" in the [comparison of application virtualization software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_application_virtualization_software)
).

So when you are writing programs in Java and running them in the standard way, it's true that your code is converted entirely to zero-operand operations.
This is true *regardless* of what physical machine eventually executes that intermediate code.

However, as @Pseudonym and others have pointed out,
most physical hardware that we use to actually run that code are "register machines", where typically "operation" instructions each have 2 sources and 1 destination.
So that intermediate code is usually *further* converted to multiple-operand instructions, since such instructions are the only kind that can be directly executed on most physical hardware.
If you write in some other language (in particular, assembly language),
then often your code is converted directly to such 2-operand or 3-operand instructions, which are later directly executed.

It is technically true that (given the same hardware to build them out of) a "stack machine" -- a CPU designed to process zero-operand instructions -- will have a faster clock rate than a "register machine" -- a CPU designed to execute multiple-operand instructions.
But clock rate isn't everything ( [megahertz myth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/megahertz_myth) ).
A single zero-operand instruction is "faster" than a single multiple-operand instruction.
But as the ["stack_machine" article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_machine) points out, stack machines require more instructions to implement any particular piece of functionality, cancelling out some or all of that advantage.